# How can I make sure my input string has only characters & is 10 letters or less?

Tags: c

I'm currently writing code for an assignment and i'm trying to error check this piece of code so that when an input string is given by the user, if it exceeds 10 characters OR contains numbers, it will loop until a valid input is given. (valid being 10 characters or less.) Here is what I have so far. I'm currently trouble shooting the STRING part. (STRING is defined as 10)

```
#define STRING 10

typedef struct
{
    char make[STRING];
    Date manufactureDate;
    Date purchaseDate;
    double purchasePrice;
}Car; 

void addCar(Car *carIn)
{
    do
    {
        printf( "\n Enter the make: ");
        scanf("%s", (*carIn).make);
    }while((*carIn).make) strlen(10));

    printf( "Manufacture date > (DD/MM/YYYY) \n");
    getDate(&(*carIn).manufactureDate);
    printf( "Purchase date > (DD/MM/YYYY) \n");
    getDate(&(*carIn).purchaseDate);

    do
    {
       printf( " Enter the purchase price (100.00 = $100.00): ");
       scanf("%lf", &(*carIn).purchasePrice);
    }while ((*carIn).purchasePrice <= 0);
}
```

Comment: defining string as 10. I've seen it all.

Comment: Do you mean 'only letters'?  You can only read characters into a string, but you probably have in mind something more restrictive.  Maybe you need a 'scan set' such as `%9[a-zA-Z]`?

Comment: I think my explanation of the question has confused some. So when the code is ran the user must input a make of the car. I want the input to only be characters a-z, A-Z & I want it to be 10 LETTERS or less. (Shouldn't of used characters.) I defined STRING as 10 because I thought I could do something like,

    } while ((*carIn).make) <= STRING;

As in, the ((*carIn).make) part has to be 10 letters of lower.

@JonathanLeffler

Comment: @alancuz What is `Car *carIn` and  `(*carIn).make`?

Comment: @rootkea Car is a pre-defined structure I used earlier in the code. (*carIn).make is what I want the make of the car to be written too.

Comment: OP, strlen is your best friend.

Comment: @Mike I came across that function while reading up about this. I'm just not sure how to incorporate it without adding in a temp variable.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*Answer started before the question was edited and the `addCar()` function extended.*</sup>

Assuming you have a structure definition along the lines of:

```
typedef struct Car Car;
struct Car
{
    …
    char make[11];
    …
};
```

Then you can write code rather like:

```
void addCar(Car *carIn)
{
    while (printf("\nEnter the make: ") > 0 &&
           scanf("%10[A-Za-z]", carIn->make) != 1)
    {
        printf("Did not recognize that!\n");
        int c;
        /* Didn't get any alpha characters - read the line and start over */
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            ;
        if (c == EOF)
        {
            printf("Farewell!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your Lamborghini owners won't be happy with you.

Note too the use of the `->` (arrow) operator; it is designed to make `(*carIn).make` unnecessary.  It dramatically simplifies the notation when structure pointers are nested inside other structures.  Compare `(*(*s1).s2).member` with `s1->s2->member`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help Jonathan, but the code you've used here is far beyond what I've learnt so far. I'm doing C as a core subject for my degree and some of the commands you've used here I've never seen before.

Comment: There are only two functions you didn't use: `getchar()` and `exit()`.  And maybe the `ptr->member` instead of `(*ptr).member`, I suppose, but you should have been told about that as soon as pointers to structures were covered.  The rest is just simply assembling it differently.  `printf()` is a function that returns the number of characters it printed; the `> 0` is mainly a way of including it in the loop control.  The test on the return value from `scanf()` is crucial; always check whether your input succeeded (and one of the most basic debugging techniques is 'print what you just read').

Comment: @JonathanLeffler @alancuz - use `#define STRING 11` to have a space for terminating `\0` byte to make `make` a valid `C` string.

Comment: @rootkea: You'll note that I hypothesize that the structure contained `char make[11];` to allow enough space for 10 characters plus a terminating null.  I also carefully limited the scan set to read at most 10 alphabetic characters.  I didn't make sure that the next character was a newline; it could be a space, a digit, a punctuation character — or, indeed, the second 'i' in Lamborghini.

Comment: @alancuz There are *statements* in C, not commands. And how didn't you learn about `->` operator when learning about pointers?